# Get device information for user who rated app

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-play

One of my apps been in the market for 3 weeks now. Got a few good ratings, but **one of the ratings I got is a 1**. Unfortunately the user didn't leave any review so I got no way of telling why is she/he dissatisfied as such.

**Is there a way that I can find what device/android version etc...they're using?**

FYI, In the developer console, I can't find any details of this rating under "Ratings & Reviews". I am only able to see information on the ones with reviews.

I have an an analytics event triggered when the user clicks the rate button but of course no information about the rating itself.

Comment: Petition google to not allow ratings without reviews?

Comment: I was actually thinking that if it's a 1, then Google should enforce user to write a review. Feedback would definitely help developers improve their apps.

Comment: My advice is to not overthink your ratings like this. People leave ratings for the dumbest reasons. Like maybe they downloaded your app thinking it did one thing and it turns out it didn't do what they thought it would. So they leave a 1 star. Or they didn't use it correctly. Or they just saw a bunch of 5 stars and thought it would be funny to leave a 1 star. There's no rhyme or reason to some of them. The ones who actually have feedback and want to suggest improvements will write a reveiw saying such.

Comment: Thanks for that, definitely helpful. My only concern is that if there's a combination of model/device/android-version that my app might be extremely misbehaving on.

Answer (score 1):

The latest 1 star ratings from my apps say "good app thank you" and "can't download it". Apparently the first user tapped on the wrong button and the other has a bad network connection and wasn't able to download the app from the store.

As you can see, you shouldn't worry about low ratings until you get more detailed reviews (you will get some eventually).